# If $x^{-} = \textrm{argmin}_x f(x) $, $x^{+} = \textrm{argmin}_x g(x) $, and $x^{-} \neq x^{+} $, then can we state the following:

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

If $x^{-} = \operatorname{argmin}_x f(x) $, $x^{+} = \operatorname{argmin}_x g(x) $, and $x^{-} \neq x^{+} $, then can we state that $x^* \neq x^-, x^+$ where $x^{*} = \operatorname{argmin}_x f(x) + g(x)$.

If the optimal point for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are different. Then can say that the optimal point for their summation is none of their optimal points, assuming that both functions are non-zero.

If this does not hold, are there conditions under which they hold?

As suggested in the comments, $f$ and $g$ have unique minimizers.

Comment: So it looks like we're assuming that $f$ and $g$ have unique minimizers? Please state all assumptions

Comment: Do you believe that with the current assumptions we cannot move forward?

Comment: Usually argmin is a set, and a minimizer is a point. Stating that something is *equal* to the argmin and not *an element of* the argmin has an error or an implication of uniqueness. If you don't mean to assume that both functions have unique minimizers, perhaps you mean $x^-\in\textrm{argmin}_x f(x)$ and so on?

Comment: Good. How about adding the assumption that argmin returns a point. In other word, $f$ and $g$ functions do not have multiple minimizers. Plus, they are distinct. Would that work?

Comment: Pretty much, although it looks like you're also assuming that $f+g$ has a unique minimizer

Comment: Yes. I was wondering how the proof would look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. For instance, $f(x)=|x|$ has a minimizer at $0$ and $g(x)=0.5|x-1|$ has a minimizer at $1$; however $f(x)+g(x)$ has a minimizer at $0$.

[Look at this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/enra8tqbj8) for a demonstration. Note that both $f$ and $g$ are convex in this example.

Comment: This might actually be true if we assume $f$ and/or $g$ are strongly convex